# Problem with install Redis when make test

Tags: redis

I use Debian 10 server at Hetzner dedicated. When i try install redis, and use command `make test` i received error:

```
[err]: CONFIG SET bind address in tests/unit/networking.tcl
Expected 'OK' to match '*Failed to bind to specified addresses*' (context: type eval line 4 cmd {assert_match {*Failed to bind to specified addresses*} $e} proc ::start_server)
[err]: Client output buffer soft limit is enforced if time is overreached in tests/unit/obuf-limits.tcl
Expected 102520 >= 100000 && 15 < 6 (context: type eval line 27 cmd {assert {$omem >= 100000 && $time_elapsed < 6}} proc ::test)

*** [err]: CONFIG SET bind address in tests/unit/networking.tcl
Expected 'OK' to match '*Failed to bind to specified addresses*' (context: type eval line 4 cmd {assert_match {*Failed to bind to specified addresses*} $e} proc ::start_server)
*** [err]: Client output buffer soft limit is enforced if time is overreached in tests/unit/obuf-limits.tcl
Expected 102520 >= 100000 && 15 < 6 (context: type eval line 27 cmd {assert {$omem >= 100000 && $time_elapsed < 6}} proc ::test)
```

At my hosts server file i have:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
# nameserver config
# IPv4
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
#138.2587.126.193        intelligent-yonath.138-628-126-844.plesk.page intelligent-yonath        
#
# IPv6
#::1    localhost.localdomain localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback      
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
2a01:4f8:172:29d2::2    intelligent-yonath.138-147-532-928.plesk.page intelligent-yonath
```

In my /etc/resolv.conf i has:

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
# nameserver config
nameserver 213.133.99.99
nameserver 213.133.100.100
nameserver 213.133.98.98
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9999
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:9898
nameserver 2a01:4f8:0:1::add:1010
```

How i understand problem with hosts or resolv conf. How i can fix problem and install Redis?